# How to fix Next js 13 The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my next JS 13 app i'm fetching items from my server and displaying them as a list. and whenever one list selected it navigates to a detail page with dynamic route. but whenever i navigate, my console throws a warning.

```
The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

even if i switched a tab and return back this warning keeps thrown double the amount. and i think this is overloading my server with request. how i'm redirecting is as follows

```
{house.images.map((img, index) => {
          return (
            <Link
              prefetch={false}
              href={{
                pathname: `/living/${house.id}`,
              }}
              key={index}
            >
              <div
                key={index}
                className=" w-full relative -z-10 pt-[100%] cursor-pointer"
              >
                <Image
                  src={img}
                  alt="profile"
                  fill
                  className="w-full h-full top-0 left-0 -z-10 object-cover rounded-2xl ease-in-out duration-200"
                />
              </div>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
```

so if this warning keeps popping does that mean it calls the server the amount of the warning? and how can i fix this error?